# PGP Crypto dataformat results in exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey.extractPrivateKey

Tags: apache-camel, gnupg

I am experimenting with the pgp component using Camel 2.12.1.  Ultimately I want to SFTP a pgp encrypted file and let Camel decrypt the file before processing.

My route:

```
from("direct:decrypt").unmarshal().pgp("file:///home/cps/.gnupg/secring.gpg", "developer", "xxx")
        .to("log:decrypt");
```

My route results in the following exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.bouncycastle.openpgp.PGPSecretKey.extractPrivateKey(Lorg/bouncycastle/openpgp/operator/PBESecretKeyDecryptor;)Lorg/bouncycastle/openpgp/PGPPrivateKey;
    at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.PGPDataFormatUtil.findPrivateKey(PGPDataFormatUtil.java:164)
    at org.apache.camel.converter.crypto.PGPDataFormatUtil.findPrivateKey(PGPDataFormatUtil.java:139)
```

My pom.xml file adds the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-crypto</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Is there some other library that needs to be included?

**Update**
Skyr's comment below reminded me that we had a different version of bouncycastle jars installed in our jre/lib/ext directory.  When I removed those files, instead I get a different exception.

```
java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.bouncycastle.asn1.DEREncodable"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:807)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:488)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:626)
```

I added the old bcpg-jdk16.jar back into jre/lib/ext and things worked!?  I am mystified at the moment as to why this worked, but I appreciate the forward progress and the assistance offered.

Comment: Just a wild guess: Did you add bouncycastle as a dependency in your pom file as well? Or does some other dependency pull in bouncycastle?
Perhaps you have two versions of BC in your classpath, one of which doesn't provide the method mentioned in the exception.

Comment: Can you use mvn depdency:tree to check if the bcgp-jdk15on's version is 1.49?

Comment: Are you sure your certificate is located at `file:///home/cps/.gnupg/secring.gpg`? Isn't it the file you want to decrypt? Does your private key contain user-id `developer` it's more often like `User <user@domain.eu>` and password is just optional.

Comment: Thanks for the help all.  I have new issues, but have made progress.  Skyr's thinking and his comment triggered a memory.  We have bouncycastle libraries installed in our jre/lib/ext directory which were creating conflicts.  I now have different issues, but the root cause of the problem described in my original question was basically duplicate jars.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the version of your bouncyCastle is not compatible with the version of your JDK.
Try:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
  <artifactId>bcpg-jdk15on</artifactId>
  <version>1.50</version>
</dependency>
```

See: https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html

---

There is also an serviceMix version:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId>
  <artifactId>
    org.apache.servicemix.bundles.bcpg-jdk15on
  </artifactId>
  <version>1.50_1</version>
</dependency>
```